# how can i get the gitlab CI Jobs error log?

Tags: gitlab-ci

[**`

> [when i try to build a pipeline job from the gitlab ci, i got some error , but i can't get the error logs so i can't resolve the problem, heres my sample pipeline script

stages:

- build
- test

variables:
LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

before_script:

- yarn install
- cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd ..
- fastlane

build:
stage: build
script:
- fastlane test
tags:
- macos

test:
stage: test
script:
- fastlane atest
tags:
- macos[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKCZX.png)

`**][2]

Answer (score 1):

The `Failed Jobs` tab only lists a summary. Please try the `Jobs` tab and click on the failed job there.

If the log doesn't contain enough details, add [debug logging](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#debug-logging)  to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

The logs for service go to [syslog](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/) or in case of systemd-based runner you can get the logs by running:
`journalctl -u gitlab-runner`

To tail the logs :
`journalctl -u gitlab-runner | tail -100`

find specific runner logs:

```
 journalctl -u gitlab-runner | tail -100 | grep "runner-id"
```